# TYPO3: Fluid inserted menu has no items

Tags: templates, menu, typoscript, fluid, items

I try to learn and understand Fluid based TYPO3 site packages better and
roughly followed this tutorial: [TYPO3 Sitepackage Tutorial](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-sitepackage/master/en-us/Index.html).
I deviated from it in a few points though, to keep it simple (I omitted everything related to Jumbotron and substituted it with a simpler menu of my own creation.

This is the partial I generated for the menu:

```
<div class="mainmenu">
*
<f:for each="{mainnavigation}" as="mainnavigationItem">
    <span class="nav-item {f:if(condition: mainnavigationItem.active, then: 'active')}">
        <a class="nav-link" 
           href="{mainnavigationItem.link}"
           target="{mainnavigationItem.target}"
           title="{mainnavigationItem.title}"
            >
            {mainnavigationItem.title}
        </a>
    </span>
</f:for>
*
</div>
```

My site package actually works to some extend and I could generate a main page and some sub pages with it. Unfortunately my menu items/sub pages links are not shown though. They are not added to the menu. It seems that the MenuProcessor object is empty. I know the respective partial is actually rendered, because I can see static parts included in the page, but nothing else. In short: The for-loop does not produce anything. I assume there are no "mainnavigationItems" found for some reason. Maybe I am just missing a simple setting somewhere, that has nothing to do with Fluid or sitepackages.

Here's the code for my **setup.typoscript** file:

```
@import 'EXT:fluid_styled_content/Configuration/TypoScript/setup.typoscript'

page = PAGE
page {
   typeNum = 0

   10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
   10 {
      templateName = TEXT
      templateName.stdWrap.cObject = CASE
      templateName.stdWrap.cObject {
         key.data = pagelayout

         pagets__site_package_default = TEXT
         pagets__site_package_default.value = Default

         default = TEXT
         default.value = Default
      }
      templateRootPaths {
         0 = EXT:site_package/Resources/Private/Templates/Page/
         1 = {$page.fluidtemplate.templateRootPath}
      }
      partialRootPaths {
         0 = EXT:site_package/Resources/Private/Partials/Page/
         1 = {$page.fluidtemplate.partialRootPath}
      }
      layoutRootPaths {
         0 = EXT:site_package/Resources/Private/Layouts/Page/
         1 = {$page.fluidtemplate.layoutRootPath}
      }
      
      dataProcessing {
        10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\MenuProcessor
        10 {
            levels = 1
            includeSpacer = 1
            as = mainnavigation     
        }
      }
      
   }

   includeCSS {
        website = EXT:site_package/Resources/Public/Css/look.css
   }

   includeJSFooter {
      website = EXT:site_package/Resources/Public/JavaScript/myscript.js
   }
}

config {
   absRefPrefix = auto
   cache_period = 86400
   debug = 0
   disablePrefixComment = 1
   doctype = html5
   extTarget =
   index_enable = 1
   index_externals = 1
   index_metatags = 1
   inlineStyle2TempFile = 1
   intTarget =
   linkVars = L
   metaCharset = utf-8
   no_cache = 0
   pageTitleFirst = 1
   prefixLocalAnchors = all
   removeDefaultJS = 0
   sendCacheHeaders = 1

   // Compression and concatenation of CSS and JS Files
   compressCss = 0
   compressJs = 0
   concatenateCss = 0
   concatenateJs = 0
}
```

Do you have any ideas, why my menu shows no items? Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I figured something out by myself: It seems I cannot place the menu in a partial. I integrated that part in the main layout template instead and now the menu items are listed.

I can only assume, that some kind of information is not automatically passed forward to where it would be needed, when the partial file is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add a starting point or a list of pages to your typoscript.

```
dataProcessing {
10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\MenuProcessor
10 {
  levels = 1
  special = list
  special.value = 1,2,3,4
  # or
  special = directory
  special.value = 3
  includeSpacer = 1
  as = mainnavigation     
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I haven't looked into the issue any further since I found a workaround by not placing the navigation inside a partial. By now I assume, that the problems stemmed from a violation of the naming convention for fluid-files. I haven't looked into the issue any futher since then though.